# what have I done wrong android studio isn't opening like the tutorial on YouTube

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am watching a tutorial on YouTube because I am new to all of this, I have been following it step by step but a terminal on android studio isn't coming up on mine like it is for his, I don't know how to fix it

[image: 1]

context Im trying flutter

I tried deleting the folder I created and recreating one but nothing comes up, I don't have a main.dart file on it

Answer (score 0):

Press `Alt + F12` to get the android studio terminal